# nuxtlink path not working correctly

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, nuxt.js

I'm working on a vue website with nuxt. On the menu, I want to get the object_slug value for the link, but it's not working..

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li v-for="item in $store.state.menu" :key="item.id">
     <nuxt-link to="{ path: 'item.object_slug' }">{{ item.title }}</nuxt-link>
  </li>
</ul>
```

On the nuxt documentation, they say :

> At the moment,  is the same as , so we recommend you to see how to use it on the Vue Router documentation.

And on the Vue Router documentation, they say this is working

> `<router-link :to="{ path: 'home' }">Home</router-link>`

I don't understand why it's not working, thanks

Comment: You forgot the `:` before `to`.

Comment: There no `:` in the `nuxt-link` doc :

`<nuxt-link to="/about">About</nuxt-link>`

https://nuxtjs.org/api/components-nuxt-link/

Comment: Yes, it's not needed in that case. Without `:`, it's handled as a plain string. If you want to pass an object, you have to use `:`.

Comment: Ok, I get it, thanks @DanielDiekmeier. `<nuxt-link :to="{ path: item.object_slug }">{{ item.title }}</nuxt-link>`